# ng-repeat on array having multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

This is my angularjs function

```
$scope.getSpecificCat = function(p_cat) {
    $http.get(url+'getSpecificCatJson/' + p_cat).success(function(data){         
    $scope.specifics = data;         
  }).error(function(){
    //alert('there is some errror while fetching product ');
  });   
}
```

The specifics contain two arrays like `[Array[2],Array[2]]`. Now my question is that how show these arrays values in `ng-repeat`.I want to elaborate my question
that first array contain data like 0:object while object have product_name:"tv"
while second array have 0:"30"
This is my modal
 public function get_specific_cat($p_cat)

```
{                 
                 $current_date = date('d-M-Y');
                 $current_new  = strtotime($current_date);
                 $this->db->select("*, ((p_bid/total_bid)*100) as progress");
                // print_r($current_new);die;
                 $this->db->where('p_cat',$p_cat); 
                 $this->db->where('p_status','active');
        $query = $this->db->get('product');
        $data  = $query->result();
         $percent_array =[];

          foreach ($data as $row) {
            $id  = $row->p_id;
            $ppr = $row->pp_date;
            $pcr = $row->pc_date;
            $ppn = strtotime($ppr);
            $pcn = strtotime($pcr);
            $p_name = $row->p_name;
             if($row->p_cat == 'diamond')
             {
              return $data;
             }
             else if($row->p_cat == 'gold' && $ppr < 1)
            {
               return $data ;
            }
            else if(!empty($pcn && $ppn) && $pcn != $ppn)
            {
            $percent_array[] = (($current_new-$ppn) * 100)/($pcn-$ppn);
          //  $percent_data = array('0' => $percent_array , );

          } 


          }

             $percent_data = array('0' =>$data, '1' => $percent_array);
             return $percent_data; 


}
```

i wand percentage as well as data for ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

So your data looks like something like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    ['Val1', 'Val2'],
    ['Val1', 'Val2']
];
```

You can loop over with 2 `ng-repeat`, as follow:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in items">
    <div ng-repeat="j in i">{{j}}</div>
</div>
```

### [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3k6hk6to/)

Comment: in this case one array contains integer array while the second array contains object

Comment: plz give a kind look to the asked question again

Comment: Provide your JSON object in your question, I don't understand what its structure is.

Comment: i added the modal return data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over all the items in all the arrays within the main array:

```
$scope.specifics = data;
$scope.specificsFlat = (data || []).reduce(function(mainArray, array) { 
  return mainArray.concat(array);
}, []);
```

Then you can use specificsFlat

```
<div ng-repeat="specific in specificsFlat">
  {{ specific.whatever }}
</div>
```

This will flatten your main array by taking the values from the sub-arrays and placing them all on the same level.

Comment: but i am unable to get second array values because i do not  know their index

Comment: i have modified my question look again